# error in delete rows from the datagridview binding provider to the Access database with dapper in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, data-binding, datagridview, dapper

I have successfully loaded the database but I still have an error problem in deleting row from the datagridview to the database. The datagridview in my code uses nuget packages "Kimtoo.Bindingprovider" and I also use nuget packages dapper with an Access database. There may be other solutions.

Thanks

```
 Public Sub New()
            If Program.IsInDesignMode(Me) Then
                Return
            End If
            InitializeComponent()
'An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Kimtoo.DbContext.dll
            grid.OnDelete(Of Student)(Function(a, b) Db.Get().Delete(a) > 0)
            LoadData()
        End Sub
        Private Sub LoadData()
            Try
                'Dim data = Db.Get().Select(Of Student)()
                Dim data As List(Of Student) = Con.Query(Of Student)("Select * From students").ToList()
                grid.Bind(data)

                If textBox1.Text.Trim().Length > 0 Then
                    grid.SearchRows(textBox1.Text.Trim())
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Sub

        Private Sub btnDel_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnDel.Click
            grid.DeleteRow(Of Student)()
        End Sub
```

```
'previous connection with the nuget packages Kimtoo.DbContext and the "Mysql" database
''Sub New()
        '    Try
        '        'setttings for mysql
        '        'Dim err = Db.Init("Server=localhost;Database=school_manager;Uid=root;SslMode=none;", MySqlDialect.Provider)
        '        If err IsNot Nothing Then
        '            MessageBox.Show(err.Message)
        '            Environment.Exit(0)
        '        End If
        '    Catch err As Exception
        '        MessageBox.Show(err.Message)
        '        Environment.Exit(0)
        '    End Try
        'End Sub
```

```
'connection now with the database "Access"
Public Function GetConnectionString() As String
        Dim strCon As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|"
        strCon &= "\school_manager.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
        Return strCon
    End Function
    Public Con As New OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString())
```

[image: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Kimtoo.DbContext.dll]

Comment: @KimTooFlex , maybe you can help me because I see your account name is the same as the nuget creator package "Kimtoo.Bindingprovider" and "Kimtoo.Dbcontext".

Answer (score 1):

Apologies i noticed this quite late. Binding Provider seems to be working well on C#, Lemme replicate the same VB.NET and i'll  update you shortly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm waiting for a reply from soon so I can use the binding provider without any problems in vb.net